# strange result when using r ets() function for analyzing CPI data

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, ets

everyone. I just started to learn time series.

I have the following monthly CPI data (2010.01 - 2015.12) from China.

I would like to do some forecast with this data using ets() function from R.

```
vector1 <- c(100.6, 101.2, 99.3, 100.2, 99.9, 99.4, 100.4, 100.6, 100.6, 100.7, 101.1, 100.5, 101.0, 101.2, 99.8, 100.1, 100.1, 100.3, 100.5, 100.3, 100.5, 100.1, 99.8, 100.3, 101.5, 99.9, 100.2, 99.9, 99.7, 99.4, 100.1, 100.6, 100.3, 99.9, 100.1, 100.8, 101.0, 101.1, 99.1, 100.2, 99.4, 100.0, 100.1, 100.5, 100.8, 100.1, 99.9, 100.3, 101.0, 100.5, 99.5, 99.7, 100.1, 99.9, 100.1, 100.2, 100.5, 100.0, 99.8, 100.3, 100.3, 101.2, 99.5, 99.8, 99.8, 100.0, 100.3, 100.5, 100.1, 99.7, 100.0, 100.5)
```

I tried to follow the procedure from the following link:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146098/ets-function-how-to-avoid-forecast-not-in-line-with-historical-data

The code is as follows:

```
train_ts<- ts(vector1, frequency=12)
fit2<-ets(train_ts, model="ZZZ", damped=TRUE, alpha=NULL, beta=NULL, gamma=NULL, 
        phi=NULL, additive.only=FALSE, lambda=TRUE, 
        lower=c(0.000,0.000,0.000,0.8),upper=c(0.9999,0.9999,0.9999,0.98), 
        opt.crit=c("lik","amse","mse","sigma","mae"), nmse=3, 
        bounds=c("both","usual","admissible"), ic=c("aicc","aic","bic"),
        restrict=TRUE)  
ets <- forecast(fit2,h=5,method ='ets') 

plot(forecast(fit2))
lines(fit2$states[,1],col='red')
```

However, I got the following graph which looks weird.
And I get alpha =0, beta =0 and gamma = 0... which seems to mean I have no trend and no seasonality?

[image]

**Sorry that I have many questions..**

1. Does the forecast look right? I think something is wrong here, but I could not figure out what is the problem.
2. what does "fit2$states[,1]" stand for? what does the red line stand for?

Thanks a lot for all your kind helps..

**I then tried to use part of the data vector[1:43]. what I got is ...**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, smoothing parameters close to zero do not mean that you have no level, trend, or seasonality. They mean that the level, trend or seasonality **do not change over time**. See https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7.

Second, you do not specify the version of the **forecast** package that you are using, or even that you are using the **forecast** package. So let's try your code using the current version of the package:

```
library(forecast)
vector1 <- c(100.6, 101.2, 99.3, 100.2, 99.9, 99.4, 100.4, 100.6,
  100.6, 100.7, 101.1, 100.5, 101.0, 101.2, 99.8, 100.1, 100.1, 100.3,
  100.5, 100.3, 100.5, 100.1, 99.8, 100.3, 101.5, 99.9, 100.2, 99.9,
  99.7, 99.4, 100.1, 100.6, 100.3, 99.9, 100.1, 100.8, 101.0, 101.1,
  99.1, 100.2, 99.4, 100.0, 100.1, 100.5, 100.8, 100.1, 99.9, 100.3,
  101.0, 100.5, 99.5, 99.7, 100.1, 99.9, 100.1, 100.2, 100.5, 100.0,
  99.8, 100.3, 100.3, 101.2, 99.5, 99.8, 99.8, 100.0, 100.3, 100.5,
  100.1, 99.7, 100.0, 100.5)
train_ts <- ts(vector1, frequency=12)
fit2 <- ets(train_ts, damped=TRUE)  
ets <- forecast(fit2, h=5) 
plot(forecast(fit2))
lines(fit2$states[,1],col='red')
```

[image]

That looks ok to me, and not the same as what you posted.

The first column of the `states` matrix contains the level of the series. In this case, the level goes through the middle of the data as you would expect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helps! I was using the latest version forecast 8.0.